# How to specify a query parameter for all requests?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm testing my API using rest-assured.

For every request I made to this API, I need to specify an apiKey query parameter such as `?apiKey=xxxx`.

So right now I can write a simple flow such as:

```
String json = given()
    .queryParam("apiKey", "xxx)
    .contentType("application/json")
    .when().get("/api/1.0/endpoint")
    .asString();
```

But using this strategy I'll need to set the apiKey for every test case. Is there a way to setup a global query parameter to be used for every test flow written with rest-assured?

Comment: What is `given()`? Change it to apply the `queryParam` to the client you return.

Answer (score 0):

you can set in to header for each request you have to set this value in the header.Like in AUTHORIZATION you can set the api key value.